# VSCode extension API for dynamically creating keybindings

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-keybinding

Trying to dynamically create keybindings from within an extension.
I can't seem to find any API that supports this.

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

This link should show you how to do it. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.keybindings

Steps:

1. register a new command (in extenson.ts)

   ```js
   let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.helloWorld', () => {
     console.log("command ran");
   });
   context.subscriptions.push(disposable);`
   ```
2. Then add it to the activation events (in package.json)

   ```js
   "activationEvents": [
     "onCommand:extension.helloWorld",
     "onCommand:extension.newComment"
   ],
   ```
3. Then declare your new command (in package.json)

   ```js
   "contributes": {
     "commands": [{
       "command": "extension.helloWorld",
       "title": "Hello World"
     }],
     "keybindings": [{
       "command": "extension.helloWorld",
       "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+k",
       "mac": "cmd+k cmd+k",
       "when": "editorTextFocus"
     }]
   },
   ```

Now whenever someone double presses k while holding cmd, the `helloWorld` command will run and "command ran" will be print to the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vscode namespace API for your extension. There is a `keybindings` section in your `package.json`. So you can define key map inside that.

For example you should use like this:

```json
{ "key": "tab", "command": "tab", "when": ... },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "editor.emmet.action.expandAbbreviation", "when": ... },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder", "when": ... },
{ "key": "tab", "command": "acceptSelectedSuggestion", "when": ... },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+k", "command": "editor.action.deleteLines", "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```

Extra helpful link: Windows virtual key list:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731

For detailed information about API and practices, please check following link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_customizing-shortcuts

Comment: That's great but I'd like to dynamically do that. Not statically as you suggested.

Comment: why do you want for ? Can you explain with an example, maybe I can help. I misunderstood you at first place, I'm sorry.

Comment: sure :) I want to write an extension that creates a keybinding according to some logic. e.g.: ... if(some_predicate) { vscode.addKeyBinding(....) ...

Comment: actually, there is "when" keyword for this kind of logic. For example; in c# code ctrl+k -> delete something, on javascript you can align code. Like this; { "key": "shift+alt+a",           "command": "editor.action.blockComment",                                     "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == csharp" },

Comment: Also you can't change keybindings without reload VScode. You have to use it like this. I checked myself, so its could be problematic. Even in your best case, you can add some logic with "when" keyword.

Comment: I understand - but I need it to be programmatic and not declerative. It would be run when VSCode is started and the extension is initialized so no problem there.

Comment: JSON does not allow variable referencing. So you can't do this on VSCode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145123/discussion-between-srfrnk-and-orhun-begendi).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by contributing all of your keybindings and using a custom where clause. See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#add-a-custom-when-clause-context